Ubuntu 24.04, Manual Install: /dev/mapper/* targets unavailable
We've got a new installer, Subiquity for Ubuntu 24.04.  I've always set up my disks properly, encrypting, opening, creating logical volumes and filesystems, etc.  Then I'd enter the installer and find the opened disks available as targets for the install.  With the new installer, that's not an option as /dev/mapper/* devices are not available.  It's a known bug in the installer, but it's been labeled "wishlist" (!?)
Question on 23.04, Bug 2058511, Bug 2064193.
I'm looking for a work-around, and I'm wondering if yaml, which seems to be the only other option, could do it.  If so, I'm looking for suggestions of how to go about that.

I resolved the problem by doing a vanilla install to disk A (it could just be a USB stick).  Then, I prepared my disks B (luks > Btrfs Raid1 with encrypted /boot).  Copying over the files from A to B, I then pivoted into B.  Modifying /etc/fstab, /etc/crypttab, and /etc/default/grub, I then ran update-initramfs, update-grub, and grub-install.  For the latter part, I found this guide helped.
